# xpath select parent based on (relative) child content

Tags: html, xml, xpath

This xpath returns both divs with the class theclass, I want to match based on it having a span with specific text content. (The real world usage the span is nested under a many nodes) so i don't want to specify the whole path for the span from the parent node.

I want to just return the first div.

XPATH

```
//div[contains(@class, "theclass")][//span[text()="this"]]
```

HTML / XML

```
<html>
<div class="theclass">
<ul>
<li>
    <strong>f</strong>
    <span>this</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="theclass">
<ul>
<li>
    <strong>g</strong>
    <span>no</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="notclass">
<ul>
<li>
    <strong>h</strong>
    <span>not</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the search in the current parent `div`'s context by adding `.`:

```
//div[contains(@class, "theclass") and .//span="this"]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//div[contains(@class, "theclass") and .//span="this"]'
<div class="theclass">
<ul>
<li>
    <strong>f</strong>
    <span>this</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I will accept the answer when the site will let me. I have to wait 10 minutes currently.